# Slow Boot in Ubuntu 15.10 on Lenovo Y500

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo, 15.10, dmesg

I am experiencing *extremely* slow boot times on my Ubuntu 15.10. It is a clean install over what used to be Windows 8.1 (with uefi).

Startup ranges from a minute to a minute and a half, with about half of it on a blank purple screen (no plymouth yet).

I have the dmesg output [here](http://pastebin.com/GJDXmQ1u). Reading through it I am having a hard time understanding what are serious issues and what are the things that should be expected.

Any help interpreting this file would be much appreciated!

Comment: That`s pretty average, Ubuntu does not start to boot until the purple screen so it is more like 30 - 45 seconds. The 15 - 20 second boot times you see around are a combination of an SSD drive and suspend / hibernate modes and wont include bios / bootloader.. One suggestion for you is edit your start up services, that may get you a second or two.

Comment: Is this a purple screen before/during GRUB? What happens when you push 'shift' about halfway through the purple screen? It quite possibly could be that GRUB is waiting for a device on your computer and it stops retrying to connect after a minute and a half or so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a minute to a minute and a half are slow boot times, for example look at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) where it shows boot times for computers, most are within the range you're experiencing.

If you would like the computer to boot faster, may I recommend purchasing an SSD drive to allow resources to load more quickly.

Good luck!